# Photoshop - how to get rid of background and resize the image inside it?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am working on this image:

[image]

And I need to get rid of that gray background, and resize the image itself. Right now if I try to resize the image, is says it is pixels: 3285 by 2000.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove neutral background in photoshop?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/62676/how-to-remove-neutral-background-in-photoshop)

Comment: @Cai yeah, I realized that after flagging...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just drag the "bg" layer to the trash can on the Layers Panel.

The "bg" layer is locked, so you'll need to first highlight the layer in the Layers Panel, then click the little Lock icon at the top of the Layers Panel. You should then be able to drag the layer to the trash icon on the Layers Panel.

[image: trash]

To remove the excess area after the background is removed, choose `Image > Trim` from the menu. Tick the Transparent Pixels option and click OK.

*Reviewing the help files for Photoshop would assist in basic operations of this nature.*

Comment: thanks, but I do not see the trash over there :) What am I missing here? :)

Comment: There is a trash icon there. It's present in every version of Photoshop. If you don't see it, your panel is off the screen, move the panel to the left.

Comment: Ah yeah actually I do see it, but it doesn't let me drag it there. Once I drag it, it disables the moving of the background to trash. Would you know why?

Comment: The layer is locked. Highlight the layer and click the little lock icon at the top of the panel. Then drag it to the trash icon.

Comment: ah yes, I just unlocked it and removed the background! But there is still a big area around the actual image (it is checkered now).  How do I get rid of that area?

Comment: Choose **Image > Trim**, tick Transparent Pixels and click Okay.

Comment: I just did that and the image became smaller, but there is still some stuff around it. Is that expected?

Comment: Yes. The trim feature removed all areas where there are no pixels. Any area left has pixels in it. If you want it smaller than that, use the Crop tool. Again, the help files will assist greatly in basic application use.

Comment: thank you for your help and I am sorry this is basic stuff.  It is just confusing at first.  I have cropped out most of the background, but what about the rounded corners? I still have some background left there.

Comment: All images are rectangular. And I mean **all images**. There's no such thing as an image without squared corners. However, if those corners are transparent, they won't show when using some image formats such as .psd or .png.

Comment: you are going to kill me, and I even did this before, but I forgot where is the option to make the background transparent. :) Would you know? :)

Comment: You haven't explained usage of the image or format you need so I could guess. But it would be better if you updated your question to include what format you want the final image in and for what use.

Comment: I needed it to be in png format :) and I was going to display it as a marketing image on a website

Comment: File > Save for Web and choose PNG24 at the top right. There will be a Transparent checkbox.

Comment: Ah right, save for web, duh-me. Thank you, you were really great and fantastic help! Have a great day :)

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

As for the background, have you tried **"Select" -> "Color range"** then selecting the background and changing the tolerance to satisfy you? For me it's the easiest way to do it.

Another way to do it is with the **Background eraser** tool. You may find more about it here: http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-quickly-easily-remove-a-background-in-photoshop/

To resize the image go to: **"Image" -> "Image size"** and simply put different values (you can also resize it there by using percent of the current size of the image).

Comment: I need to get rid of the background completely, not just hide it :)

Comment: When it's selected, you can just delete it by clicking "delete" on your keyboard.

Comment: And does it matter if I do this on a .png or a .psd? Does it have to be psd?

Comment: Right now when I do select --> color range. I do not see a way to get rid of the background.

Comment: In psd file you can hide layers with similar colors which you don't want selected (if you have them). It works with png files and I think it should work in this case, you just have to accurately set the tolerance.

Comment: what is the tolerance? I don't see that option there.

Comment: Based on the screen shot in the question, this is all unnecessary.