# How to make only image white and remove white background?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, creative-cloud

How can I remove white background using photoshop from image and make it white and by duplicating original one, make it in multiply mode ? So basically it should be two images, one original (with white background) but in multiply mode and another one identical but all white and below original.[image] there is a picture how it should be like. Thanks in advance. P.s. without using magic wand or levels, there is some how possible to make like that and after that, just simply use multiply and all image is without white background

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove white background from white object](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/79382/remove-white-background-from-white-object)

Answer (score 2):

Using the **Pen Tool** with this options from the **Top Panel Tool Options** :

**Shape**, fill= white, stroke= none

Draw the cooking pots borders, if the color hide the pen drawing, press <kbd>1</kbd> to change the opacity layer to 10%. When finish change it to 100% opacity.

[image: pot]

- When ready, you get the *White Layer*
- Pressing <kbd>Cmnd</kbd> Mac / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> Win, click on the
  *White Layer* icon to get the image selection
- Activate the image layer and click <kbd>Cmnd</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> Mac / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> Win to copy the selection in a new layer
- With this you get the *Image Layer*

[image: Image Layer]

*The image used as example it's by [Jeremy Lwanga](https://unsplash.com/photos/uUwEAW5jFLE) from unsplash.com

Answer (score 0):

You obviously do not accept "select color range" tool, too. You need something which is capable to find the borders of the real hard objects and makes a selection along them excluding the background and shadows, but including white reflections on the metal. (it knows, what is reflection by reasoning, not by color)

In this case the software should find "it's two kettles made of stainless steel and a piece of basilica, the kettles have covers with loop handles"

Unfortunately such consciousness of the structure of our world isn't still included to Photoshop, you need something that is probably available only for NSA, CIA, FBI or others who do not ask the price.

I'm afraid you must draw a path along the supposed edge and turn it to a selection. That has been the only bomb proof way to exact object separations and background removals since the birth of Photoshop. Learn it from Photoshop documentation and background removal using paths -tutorials.

BTW. There's no need of such things as layer multiply when you have removed the background along a drawn path. Simply add a new background layer

[image].