# How do I automate batch processing of product photography to get a perfect white background?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, background, batch-processing, actions

[image: ProductImage]I am taking very large volume of product photography. I am using a photography tent and shooting on a white background but I need the finished images to be of the image on a perfectly white background.

I am looking for a way to automate this process as much as possible as I am going to be generating and processing thousands of images.

Does anyone know of a way to automate this process in photoshop? If not photoshop, any other software that can do this for me? All help is much appreciated.

Kind regards

edit: I have added a sample image to the post. I am looking for a way to make the background perfect white but to automate the process as much as possible so I can batch process them. The products are all food and drink products. Thanks in advance for any help and advice offered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove neutral background in photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/62676/how-to-remove-neutral-background-in-photoshop)

Comment: You can probably just create an Action to run the steps in the duplicate question

Comment: Not at all sure this is a duplicate. @Darren - Can you post an example of an image you need processed please - Are all the items similar? Vastly different?

Comment: The lighting appears flat but your product shot is underexposed. Correct exposure could make your work easier.

Comment: I'm confused because you say you're shooting on white but that looks like 50% gray. If you shoot on a white background with proper lighting you wouldn't get the above result.

Comment: I think you should address problems with the photography before you try to solve the problem in post. If you simply raise the exposure that background would be white in the first place. It's always the best procedure to take the best shot you can first, and honestly that shot can be radically improved, and not even with much difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

Make an action which simply moves the white limit in curves or levels:

[image]

It should work ok if you have consistent exposure. It's useless if every image is exposed differently.