# Replace fabric background with a solid light grey

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background-removal

In Adobe Photoshop (Version: 23.1.1 20220106.r.202 060a6d1  x64).

What is the easiest way (as in effective and quick) of replacing the fabric backdrop on this image:

[image: image on fabric backdrop]

To a solid light grey `#f6f6f6`?

I know I can go around the subject with the Pen Tool and crop him out, but that takes a long time especially when you have to do it for 10s, 100s of images.

Comment: If you want to automate it, try *Select > Subject*. Then add a layer mask. Make a new layer underneath and fill with grey.

Comment: This is the primary reason why you want to light the background separately and have the model stand further away from the background.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove neutral background in photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/62676/how-to-remove-neutral-background-in-photoshop)

Comment: @Luciano - It's kind of a dupe, but this one is so much simpler, as Billy says, it's almost a one-button fix in Select Subject/Select & Mask. [Probably even easier with the new AI tools in latest Ps, but the newest versions won't run on my Mac.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Artificial intelligence based modern background removal methods might be useful. I do not have them (I use legacy software and freeware). An old fashioned method is to make a selection which cover the background area with the Quick Selection tool.

You have mostly quite sharp edges ==> It succeeded well except at the tight corner of the eyelash and the overexposed top side of the left hand. I fixed them with the polygonal lasso. It can be used to augment or contract what the Quick Selection tool made (after a couple of iterations in + and - modes).

The selection can be used to remove the background from the image layer. Then one can insert a new separate background layer. Here's an example with a new f6f6f6 background:

[image]

The brightness of the new grey cannot be much different than the original canvas because the edge of the person contains a 1...2 px wide mix of the background and the person+clothes. The mixed area starts to look a stroke if the new grey is much darker or Brighter than the original.

This can be avoided by applying to the selection (when it was otherwise fully ready) Select > Modify > Expand > 1 or 2 px. That's essentially shaving off the mixed zone. In high resolution images that's nothing, but low resolution images can start  to look like a slice was removed. ==> Use the highest resolution version you have.

An example: Black BG, no edge shaving:

[image]

If you have transparent, blurred or no-contrast edges in some images, you must draw a path to make the selection or paint manually a layer mask. In addition one must often fix the transparent zone at the edge. Finest background removal tool have color contamination fixing which removes the background color which is seen through the transparent zone. An alternative is to clone or smudge solid material over the transparent zone.

Your image actually has a transparent edge zone: The bottom of the beard. I fixed it by cloning non-transparent beard to it. Then expanding the background selection by 1 pixel gave this result:

[image]

**Not asked:** The easiest method to solve the problem is to think it beforehand. With well set light and background one can use very fast methods to create perfect selections. Those techniques are well described elsewhere and they belong to the core skill set of a pro studio photographer. The needed room and background sizes to get some distance from the B.G. to the photographed people and the cost of having different backgrounds and good lights can be a surprise.

In theory background details could be faded from the picture if the background was so distant that the lens makes it blurry due the limited depth of the field. Modern cameras can simulate the effect in software, but I have not seen it in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe themselves now provide this as an online service.
You need to sign up but otherwise it seems to be completely free.
https://express.adobe.com/tools/remove-background

This is what I got from a one-button press, to which I added the background…

[image]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>
It's not absolutely perfect, but I don't go through any manual refinement steps.

Comment: That service is made to advertise Photoshop's one click background removal capability, which really is good. If the object could be selected with the quick selection tool the one click process will perform well - even the mixed color zone in the edge is fixed automatically. The beard is partially missed, but the error is difficult to see and easy to patch manually. Adobe's one click process cannot handle cases where the quick selection method is useless. A human is still needed to decide the clipping border::  https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3sph.png  (=found no green parts of the plant)